# homogenous containers, derived classes, initializer lists and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, variadic-templates

I have code that makes use of some dirty tricks to make it appear as *what I believe is* a nice interface. The most important class, `Worker`, is designed to make the caller construct it with temporaries; the constructor will then take them. I think the code is self-explanatory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    virtual void
        print
        ( void )
        {
            cout << "Base" << endl;
        };
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
    virtual void
        print
        ( void )
        {
            cout << "Derived1" << endl;
        };
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    virtual void
        print
        ( void )
        {
            cout << "Derived2" << endl;
        };
};

class Worker
{
    private:
        /* Arrays can't hold references, and
         * vectors are homogenous, so the
         * only option is to use (smart) pointers. */
        vector< unique_ptr<Base> >
            V
            ;

        /* The dirty trick I spoke about. */
        template<typename T> void
            init
            ( T && t )
            {
                V.emplace_back( new T( forward<T>(t) ) );
                return;
            };
        template<typename T , typename ... U> void
            init
            ( T && t , U && ... u )
            {
                V.emplace_back( new T( forward<T>(t) ) );
                    /* The usage of std::move() is explained below. */
                init(move(u)...);
                return;
            };

    public:
        template<typename ... T>
            Worker
            ( T && ... t )
            {
                    /* Use std::move() because, inside the body
                     * of the function, the arguments are lvalues.
                     * If I hadn't put std::move(), the compiler
                     * would complain about an attempt of using
                     * _new_ with a reference type (above). */
                init(move(t)...);
                return;
            };

        void
            work
            ( void )
            {
                for ( const auto & x : V )
                    x->print();
                return;
            };
};

int
main
    ( void )
{
    /* The goal: be able to create an instance of Worker
     * passing temporaries to the constructor. No initializer_list
     * is involved, no copies are made; clean, fast moves. */
    Worker worker{ Derived1() , Base() , Derived2() };
    /* This should print "Derived1\nBase\nDerived2\n". */
    worker.work();

    return 0;
}
```

Even though it compiles fine (g++ 4.8.1) and works out of the box, I feel this is not the best way to achieve my goals, and I'd like to get rid of that annoying feeling. Has anyone found another workaround for this? Are there any better aproaches, any disadvantages with my design?

Thanks in advance. The code should compile just fine, and show how I'd like my interface to be designed and why I've made use of those "tricks". Best regards,
Kalrish

Comment: "Are there any better aproaches, any disadvantages with my design?" Sounds like a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @DyP There's no destructor as the vector would destruct itself and its elements. `unique_ptr`s automatically handle the memory they manage. That's one of the reasons to use them.

Comment: `template<typename T> void init(T&& t) { V.emplace_back( new T( move(t) ) ); /*...*/` this is dangerous, because the passed argument might have been an lvalue (`T&&` is the universal-reference "idiom"). You might want to consider perfect forwarding via `std::forward<T>(t)`.

Comment: @DyP You're right. Sorry, and thank you. I've also applied `std::forward`.

Comment: @Kalrish: But `Base` needs a virtual destructor, since the unique pointers will delete a pointer to `Base` that may actually point to a derived class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ah you're right. I wasn't entirely sure. `shared_ptr` allows this, as it creates the deleter in the ctor, but `unique_ptr` uses a fixed deleter.

Comment: @Kalrish The same comment about perfect forwarding applies to the ctor of `Worker`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm nevertheless going to keep the code as it is, for the shake of simplicity, as the structs I've used do not have any member variable. As DyP pointed out, I don't need a virtual destructor _in this particular example_. (Nice to know, though. I hadn't noticed that.)

Comment: @Kalrish: Then you'll be relying on undefined behaviour. DyP is wrong: unlike `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` doesn't store a deleter. The deleter is part of the pointer's type, so all the pointers in your container will have the same deleter. It will delete a pointer to `Base`, which will give undefined behaviour if the pointer is to a derived class and there's no virtual destructor.

Comment: If you have public inheritance, you need a virtual destructor, period, end of story. What if there is a loophole in the language that allows you to avoid UB in your particular case even without a virtual destructor? Then you need a virtual destructor anyway. It costs nothing and may save huge headaches in the future. A total no-brainer.

Comment: @n.m. You need a virtual dtor if you delete an object using a pointer to a base class subobject. I agree it saves huge headaches, but it isn't required if you delete the objects always with the correct static type (e.g. `make_shared`). It costs something, but that is negligible in most cases (other than a trivial dtor called on many objects). @MikeSeymor You're right (as I said before) that we have UB here, but *warning pedantic* a `unique_ptr` *does* store a deleter (but the type of that is a fixed part of the type of the `unique_ptr`). The default deleter invokes UB here.

Comment: @DyP: Sorry, you're right; for some reason I thought `unique_ptr` only stored the managed pointer, but it does indeed store the deleter too. So, in principle, you could mess around with a custom deleter type to avoid needing a virtual destructor; but as you say you can't just rely on the default deleter.

Answer (score 1):

Though I still think this question better belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), here's an alternative version for your "dirty trick"

```
    template < typename T >
    int emplace_back(T&& t)
    {
        V.emplace_back( std::forward<T>(t) );
        return 0;
    }

    template<typename ... T>
        Worker
        ( T && ... t )
        {
            auto i = {emplace_back(new T{forward<T>(t)})...};
        };
```

Or, if you want to get rid of that member function:

```
public:
    template<typename ... T>
        Worker
        ( T && ... t )
        {
            using up = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
            auto f = [&](up&& p)
                { V.emplace_back(std::move(p)); return 0; };

            auto i = {f( up{new T{forward<T>(t)}} )...};
        };
```

You might get a warning because `i` is unused, though. This variable is only required to build an initializer-list, where a pack-expansion is allowed.

---

Normally, I'd suggest using an initializer-list instead of the variadic template ctor (that's what they're made for), but they don't support moving out the elements as they don't own their storage.

The same problem occurs if you want to initialize the `vector` in the mem-initializer-list of the ctor (via pack expansion like in the alternative above).